# MS Access VBA: When opening a report, what event is triggered once the query that the report depends on has been completed?

Tags: ms-access, events, report

I have a report that is dependent on a query. The report displays correctly but I'm trying to have a label's visibility dependent on a yes/no field in the query.

The following produces *error 2424 that the field isn't found*:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
lblUppersIncluded.Visible = ysnUppersIncluded
End Sub
```

Alternatively:

```
Private Sub Report_Activate()
lblUppersIncluded.Visible = ysnUppersIncluded
End Sub
```

Gives *error 2427 expression has no value*. Similarly for Report_Load.

However, a command box created on the report that executes the same line of code executes correctly.

I suspect that all of the Report events are triggered before the query has been run so those fields have not been populated. Is there an event that I can use after the query has been completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the best way around problems like this is to convert your label to a text box and use conditional formatting. If your formatting needs are not met by what can be accomplished by conditional formatting then you can look into code.

Specifically for a label to be visible or not you don't even need conditional formatting. Convert to text box and use:

```
=IIF([My condition for visible label],"My Label text:","")
```

as its control source.

Comment: Thanks for that tip @SunKnight0, your approach is much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that code dependent on the query fields will work if the Detail_Format event is used. This event is triggered in Print Preview view but not in Report View.